# object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, unity3d

Boa Noite, tou tentando pegar uma função que estar em outro script e passar ela para um botão, só que estar dando esse erro que estar no titulo.

```
int indice;
public Button Ant;
public ScriptName Script;

void Start() {
    call();
}

void call() {
    if (indice <= 0) { indice = 0; }

    if (indice >= 1) {
        indice = 1;
    }

    if (indice == 0)
    {
        Ant.GetComponent<ScriptName>().anteriorobj();//assim não funciona
        Ant.GetComponent<Script>().anteriorobj();//assim tambem não funcioa
    }
    else if (indice == 1)
    {
    //blablabla
    }
}

public class ScriptName : MonoBehaviour {
    public void anteriorobj()
    {
        Debug.Log("Active");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes simplesmente criar uma propriedade na classe que queres usar a class `ScriptName`

exemplo:

```
public ScriptName script;
```

e acessas assim:

```
script.anteriorobj();
```

lembrando que tens de arrastar o `ScriptName` para a propriedade no inspector

Comment: Então como estar na descrição, queria pegar essa função script.anteriorobj e setar ela em uma variavel button

Answer (score -1):

- A variável `Ant` deve estar atribuída no **Inspector**.
- O GameObject referenciado na variável anterior (`Ant`) deve possuir o component `ScriptName`.

Se estiver faltando alguma referência ele dará o erro mencionado.